# 2-Way Sync between tabs in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that is supposed to sync 2 columns in two different tabs. For some reason it's not working. Thanks! Here is the script:

```
function onEdit(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp;
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheet1 = sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2');

  var cell = e.range;
  var value = cell.getValue();
  var currentRow = cell.getRow();
  var currentColumn = cell.getColumn();

  var activeWorksheet = ['Sheet1','Sheet2'];
  var columnEdit = [1,2];

  if( activeWorksheet.indexOf(ss.getActiveSheet().getName()) > -1 && columnEdit.indexOf(currentColumn) > -1 && currentRow > 1){
    sheet1.getRange(currentRow. currentColumn).setValue(value);
    sheet2.getRange(currentRow, currentColumn).setValue(value);
  };
};
```

Comment: typo mistake `sheet1.getRange(currentRow, currentColumn).setValue(value);`

Comment: Wow.. thanks!! missed that one little typo! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Typo mistake

```
sheet1.getRange(currentRow, currentColumn).setValue(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const n = sh.getName()
  const shts = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3'];
  const cols = [1, 2, 4];
  if (~shts.indexOf(n) && ~cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    //e.source.toast(n);
    shts.forEach(s => {
      if(s != n)e.source.getSheetByName(s).getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnStart).setValue(e.value);//only writes to the sheets not edited
    });
  }
}
```

You can add more columns and sheet names if you wish